# Reading Json text response from url with PowerBi Desktop

Tags: javascript, python, json, powerbi

I am new to PowerBi.
I would like to get a table on PowerIb, from this [JSON API](https://hptrial.pythonanywhere.com/rest_api_data)

Sample of data:

```
{"data": [{"user_id": 54710, "hp_user_id": 5806514, "username": "Jay_J1", "user_profile_url": "https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/5806514", "user_blocked": 0, "hp_post_id": 8550808, "post_datetime": "2022-11-28 10:54:00", "post_url": "https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/HP-Envy-360-broken-left-hinge-and-screen-separating/m-p/8550808?search-action-id=587041408161&search-result-uid=8550808", "post_summary": "Like many others have experienced, the hinge on my HP Envy 360 broke last night. All I did was simply open it, but I heard a crack, and now the metal part is stuck at an angle to where I can no l...", "me_too": "", "post_tags": "\"[\"HP ENVY x360 Laptop - 15m-ee0023dx\",\"Microsoft Windows 11\"]\""}, {"user_id": 52629, "hp_user_id": 5800465, "username": "BrookeDorbit", "user_profile_url": "https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/5800465", "user_blocked": 0, "hp_post_id": 8550124, "post_datetime": "2022-11-27 15:39:00", "post_url": "https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Hinge-Issue/m-p/8550124?search-action-id=586827468132&search-result-uid=8550124", "post_summary": "I\u2019ve seen many others mention the same issue with their HP envy laptop but I am just as upset. I purchased my laptop in the summer of 2020 and only 2 years later, the hinge is broken. I have never o...", "me_too": "\"[{\"username\":\"Jay_J1\",\"hp_user_id\":\"5806514\",\"post_datetime\":\"2022-11-28\"}]\"", "post_tags": "\"[\"HP ENVY Laptop - 13t-ba000 CTO\"]\""},
]}
```

I can change the JSON Response if needed.

So far, I followed these steps:

- Click on "New Source" and select "JSON" or "Web" (same issue):

[image]

- Then I get a select between Html and Text which is fair:

[image]

And if I select Text, I get the text of the JSON, which is fair...

My question is how would I get the table associated with this JSON response.
As well is it possible to skip the GUI and import the Json text in Python or JS, and deliver it to the GUI?

End result, would be a table with the items in the "data" key.

Thanks a lot, and best!

Comment: Whoever marked it down, please suggest a better way, As mentioned I am a newby, and hapyy to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you are converting a plain JSON to a table. The JSON just happens to be sourced as plaintext from a URL.

JSON-to-table is well-explained in the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/json.

Additionally, I highly recommend going through this **excellent** Power Query primer - https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/11/17/4107/power-query-m-primer-part1-introduction-simple-expressions-let.

Comment: Agreed, but have you tried to do it?

Comment: This is basic, fundamental, and thoroughly documented power query. It even implements via GUI, with zero code edits.

Answer (score -1):

I got an answer from another website and it worked:

Steps to follow:

1. from "New Source", select "Blank Query" (at the full bottom)
2. Inthe ribons, select "Advanced Editor"
3. Write "your code" in M (not easy...)

```
= let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://hptrial.pythonanywhere.com/rest_api_data")),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"user_id", "hp_user_id", "username", "user_profile_url", "user_blocked", "hp_post_id", "post_datetime", "post_url", "post_summary", "me_too", "post_tags"}, {"user_id", "hp_user_id", "username", "user_profile_url", "user_blocked", "hp_post_id", "post_datetime", "post_url", "post_summary", "me_too", "post_tags"})
```

All done thanks to: [ppm](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/443516)
Tx a lot

Answer found on: [this website](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Getting-a-table-from-a-Json-text-response-url-with-PowerBi/m-p/2937109#M1007120)

Comment: Whoever  marked it down, please suggest a better way, As mentioned I am a newby, and hapyy to learn!